# SP2013 Filter documents based on tag

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, filter, key-filter

I have a SharePoint 2013 with a document central deployed. In that central I have four document applications; manuals, routines, marketing, price-list. Each category contains documents from four different areas; IT, Print, Phone, Administration.
I would like to have a filter that the user can activate when browsing the document applications. If i work in the IT department I would like to only see documents with the tag IT when clicking trough manuals, routines, marketing and price-list.

I have managed to get URL based filtering to work and with a link pass the Managed Metadata tag (Company keyworld (Tag), It's called "Företagsnyckelord" in Swedish and I don't know the equivalent world for that, sorry).

The problem is that the URL filter is not active for the entire browsing experience. It's only active in the first document library that I visit.

I have tried different kinds of filter but I can't find a filter other than URL that works with document libraries.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it but not in a perfect way. On the document library for let´s say manuals i have added links to the same location that I'm currently in but also appending a QueryString to the link with the category I want to see. Then adding a URL filter that gets the QueryString. It would bee nice if I where able to use the filter on/off webpart but as it seams I can't. Thanks for your answer PirateEric

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd want to use the Current User filter so that you can pass the department field as the filter.  In each document library you'd just add the filter above the document library web part and connect it. This would require that the user's department in their profile matches your field exactly.

Comment: I've tried that but that doesn't allow me to inactivate the filter when I want to during browsing.